# Somar a data de hoje pelo numero de horas estimado em viagem

Tags: php

Recebo um valor em formato de Horas e Minutos exemplo:

> "09:00" horas e minutos

Preciso pegar a data de hoje fazer a soma horas e minutos e apresentar exemplo:

> chega hoje as 17:30 horas e minutos

Caso o valor que eu receba for muito alto que passe de dias por exemplo:

> "36:00" horas e minutos

Pela data de hoje e hora apresentar

> chega amanha as 19:20

Coloquei abaixo abaixo de mais ou menos do que preciso:

```
<?php 
$times = array(
date('H:I'),
'01:10',
);

$seconds = 0;

foreach ( $times as $time )
{
list( $g, $i ) = explode( ':', $time );
$seconds += $g * 3600;
$seconds += $i * 60;
}

$hours = floor( $seconds / 3600 );
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;
$minutes = floor( $seconds / 60 );

echo "{$hours}:{$minutes} h";
?>
```

Comment: O que tentou fazer? Verificou as [funções de data/hora do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php) para ver se há alguma que possa lhe ajudar?

Comment: Oi Anderson tentei mais nao consegui

Comment: Poderia adicionar na pergunta sua tentativa e o resultado obtido? Se deu erro, coloque a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Ok fazendo isso

Comment: Coloquei la mais esse codigo funciona só se o dia for hoje, no caso anderson eu acho que preciso primeiro converter horas minutos em data e depois converter em semanas e apresentar ne ?

Comment: então, amanhã, depois de amanha e depois o que vai colocar?

Comment: Preciso apresenta tipo chega quinta feira dia 08/11/2018 as 17:22 exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$addHoras="48";
//$addHoras="4:10";
//$addHoras="4:1";
//$addHoras="0:01";
//$addHoras=" :60";
//transforma em minutos

$final=explode(":",$addHoras);
$addMinutos = ($addHoras*60) + (end($final));


$dataAtual=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//hora a ser exibida
$horaChegada = date('H:i', strtotime($dataAtual. " + {$addMinutos} minutes"));

$numDiaHoje= date('d');

$numDiaChegada = date('d', strtotime($dataAtual. " + {$addMinutos} minutes"));


if ($numDiaChegada==$numDiaHoje){

    echo "chego as " .$horaChegada."hs";

}elseif (($numDiaChegada-$numDiaHoje==1)){

    echo "Chego amanhã as " .$horaChegada."hs";

}elseif (($numDiaChegada-$numDiaHoje==2)){

    echo "Chego depois de amanhã as " .$horaChegada."hs";

}else{

    $dia_chegada = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dataAtual. " + {$addMinutos} minutes"));
    echo "Chego " .ucfirst(strftime("%A", strtotime($dia_chegada))). " " . $horaChegada . "hs";
}
```

Pode testar em [PHPTester](http://phptester.net/) que dá suporte setlocale - basta colar o código lá e clicar em click to test your code php

Comment: Perfeito meu nobre obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

a forma correta para se somar horas a uma data é esta

```
    $startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    //exibir a hora de início
    echo 'Starting Time: '.$startTime;

    //adiciona 1 hora ao tempo
    $cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 hour',strtotime($startTime)));

    //exibir o tempo convertido
    echo 'Converted Time (added 1 hour): '.$cenvertedTime;

    //adiciona 1 hora e 30 minutos ao horário
    $cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 hour +30 minutes',strtotime($startTime)));

    //exibir o tempo convertido
    echo 'Converted Time (added 1 hour & 30 minutes): '.$cenvertedTime;

    //adiciona 1 hora, 30 minutos e 45 segundos ao horário
    $cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 hour +30 minutes +45 seconds',strtotime($startTime)));

    //exibir o tempo convertido
    echo 'Converted Time (added 1 hour, 30 minutes  & 45 seconds): '.$cenvertedTime;

    //adiciona 1 dia, 1 hora, 30 minutos e 45 segundos ao horário
    $cenvertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+1 day +1 hour +30 minutes +45 seconds',strtotime($startTime)));

    //exibir o tempo convertido
    echo 'Converted Time (added 1 day, 1 hour, 30 minutes  & 45 seconds): '.$cenvertedTime;
```

espero que com este tutorial você entenda como manipular suas datas e predizer o dia hora minuto e segundo de chegada.

segue uma função de calculo de diferença de tempo que tinha pronta aqui:

```
function timediff($inicio,$fim){
   $entrada = $inicio;
   $saida = $fim;
   $hora1 = explode(":",$entrada);
   $hora2 = explode(":",$saida);
   $acumulador1 = ($hora1[0] * 3600) + ($hora1[1] * 60) + $hora1[2];
   $acumulador2 = ($hora2[0] * 3600) + ($hora2[1] * 60) + $hora2[2];
   $resultado = $acumulador2 - $acumulador1;
   $hora_ponto = floor($resultado / 3600);
   $resultado = $resultado - ($hora_ponto * 3600);
   $min_ponto = floor($resultado / 60);
   $resultado = $resultado - ($min_ponto * 60);
   $secs_ponto = $resultado;
   //Grava na variável resultado final
   $tempo = $hora_ponto.":".$min_ponto.":".$secs_ponto;
   return $tempo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal com muito trabalho meio que na gambiarra "rsrsr" mais saiu se alguem estiver uma ideia melhor é so postar aqui obrigado pessoal:

```html
<?php 
//Primeito vou separar hora do minutos
$estimado ='48:10'; 
$separador=explode(":",$estimado); 

$horas =  $separador[0];
$minutos =  $separador[1];


//Agora vou somar a data de hoje + horas e minutos
$data_hoje = date("d-m-Y H:i");
$soma_das_datas = date('d-m-Y H:i',strtotime('+'.$horas.' hour +'.$minutos.' minutes',strtotime($data_hoje)));
 
 
// Agora vou descobrir o dia da semana dessa data 
$diasemana = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Ter&ccedil;a', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'S&aacute;bado');
$data = $soma_das_datas;

// Varivel que recebe o dia da semana (0 = Domingo, 1 = Segunda ...)
$diasemana_numero = date('w', strtotime($data));

// Exibe o dia da semana com o Array

if ($diasemana[$diasemana_numero] == $diasemana[date('w', strtotime(date('d-m-Y')))]) {

$previsao = 'Hoje '.'as '.date('H:i', strtotime($soma_das_datas));



} else {

$previsao = $diasemana[$diasemana_numero].' as '.date('H:i', strtotime($soma_das_datas));


}

echo $previsao;

?>
```